# Who deals more damage with minigun ‒ Wolfe or Wildcat?

Tags: alien-swarm

In characters stats I can see that Wildcat's *Damage Bonus* is `4/5`, while Wolfe's is only `2/5`. *Piercing bullets* doesn't have much difference.
However, I most often see people choosing Wolfe and minigun even though his advantage is only for *Autogun Damage*.

My question is... who of them actually deals more damage with minigun?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Alien Swarm Wiki](http://alienswarm.wikia.com/wiki/Autogun_Damage) the *Autogun damage* skill increases both, Autogun and Minigun damage, while the generic *Damage bonus* does not affect the Minigun.

This means that Wolfe does more damage with the Minigun than Wildcat.

Comment: Keep in mind that most people won't wait up on Wolfe to trudge through a level with his autogun, leaving you alone and vulnerable. Wildcat has the highest speed in the game, allowing her to keep up with the team.